# Ranking query results by aggregate (count)

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get ranked values by an aggregate function - and I'd like to see if it can be done within the MySQL query (rather than the ORM calling the query).

The table and data I have is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `interactions` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `interactions` VALUES
(1, "xyz", "2017-01-01 00:05:01"),
(2, "xyz", "2017-01-01 00:05:10"),
(3, "abc", "2017-01-01 00:05:21"),
(4, "xyz", "2017-01-01 00:05:43"),
(5, "def", "2017-01-01 00:05:47"),
(6, "xyz", "2017-01-01 00:05:49"),
(7, "abc", "2017-01-01 00:05:50"),
(8, "abc", "2017-01-01 00:05:59");
```

So far I have:

```
set @curRank := 0;

select
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
    der.account,
    der.searches
from
    interactions
right join
    (select account, count(id) AS searches from interactions group by account order by searches) AS der
on
    der.account = interactions.account;
```

But this outputs every account (with the correct `searches` value - but ranked more than once):

```
 1    abc        3
 2    abc        3
 3    abc        3
 4    def        1
 5    xyz        4
 6    xyz        4
 7    xyz        4
 8    xyz        4
```

I'm looking for:

```
 1    abc        3
 2    def        1
 3    xyz        4
```

I should mention that I don't care about joint ranks - if two accounts end up with the same count in the table, then it doesn't matter if they are ranked one after the other (or what order).

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry - can you please indicate what you think is missing from this question? Just a dataset?

Comment: The linked answer is self explanatory

Comment: The linked answer is nice and detailed - but simply mentioning what you think is missing along with the link would be more helpful. Please let me know if there's any other detail missing from my question

Comment: Well, I think you've covered it

Comment: I don't understand the ids in the result

Comment: There are no IDs in the result - there is rank, account and count(id) (searches)

Comment: every day some one ask this question :)

Comment: @sumit - I found questions from people looking to rank - but not based on aggregates

Comment: It might help if you label the columns in the result set

Answer (score 0):

Adding a DISTINCT to the SELECT fixes the query:

```
set @curRank := 0;

select distinct 
    der.account,
    der.searches,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
from
    interactions
right join
    (select account, count(id) AS searches from interactions group by account order by searches) AS der
on
    der.account = interactions.account;
```